# qmake not generating binary resource files

Tags: qt, makefile, qt-creator, qmake

Specs: Qt Creator 2.5.1, Qt 4.7.4(32bit)

It is my understanding from the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/resources.html) that including a resource (.qrc) in the .pro file of Qt is all that is required to get qmake to generate the correct qrc_*.cpp files.  That doesn't seem to be the case for my project.  When running qmake the makes files are created and there are references to the qrc_ file I'm looking for under compiler_rcc_clean, just not in the build chain.

[Update]
At a suggestion from comments below the makefile generated by qmake was tested directly w/ NMAKE.  The correct qrc_filter_ao.cpp file was created.  However the IDE still fails to properly generate this file when I build from Qt Creator.

.pro:

```
include (../../shared.pri)

TARGET = filter_ao
QT += opengl

HEADERS += ./filter_ao.h
SOURCES += ./filter_ao.cpp

RESOURCES += \
    filter_ao.qrc
```

shared.pri

```
include (./general.pri)
VCGDIR = ../$$VCGDIR
TEMPLATE      = lib
CONFIG       += plugin
CONFIG       += resources
QT += opengl
QT += xml
QT += xmlpatterns
QT += script

win32-msvc2008:  LIBS += ../../distrib/common.lib
win32-msvc2008:DEFINES += GLEW_STATIC _USE_MATH_DEFINES

INCLUDEPATH  *= ../.. $$VCGDIR ../$$GLEWDIR/include
DEPENDPATH += ../.. $$VCGDIR

win32-msvc2008:DEFINES  += _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
CONFIG(release,debug | release){
  # Uncomment the following line to disable assert in mingw
  #DEFINES += NDEBUG
}

DESTDIR       = ../../distrib/plugins
contains(TEMPLATE,lib) {
  CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
     unix:TARGET = $$member(TARGET, 0)_debug
     else:TARGET = $$member(TARGET, 0)d
  }
}
win32-msvc2008: RCC_DIR = $(ConfigurationName)
```

general.pri

```
 VCGDIR = ../../../vcglib
 GLEWDIR = ../external/glew-1.7.0
 win32:DEFINES += NOMINMAX
```

Comment: I think the problem is in this line: `win32-msvc2008: RCC_DIR =  $(ConfigurationName)`  
try `./tmp` instead and make sure that problem isn't there. The value of variables should be received by using double $ sign. Not one. Also resources shouldn't be different in different build configurations.

Comment: @Pie_Jesu I think you are right. RCC_DIR seems to be the issue. See my answer below.

Comment: @Pie_Jesu I didn't even see this comment, my apologies.  Wish I had, 2 days ago I'd have fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @Pie_Jesu is correct. I have set up a directory structure with the files from the OP, and imported the .pro file into QtCreator. I have removed the "win32-msvc2008: " prefix from the line which sets RCC_DIR since I am using VS Express 2010.
Result was that I get a message like "Unable to open \qrc_filter_ao.cpp for writing: Access denied" and no qrc_file is being created.
I then set the line to /TEMP:

```
RCC_DIR = /TEMP
```

Result is that I find the qrc_ file below \TEMP.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with a simpler .pro file? For instance, the following works for me (On Linux, no MSVC env available currently):

```
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG       += plugin
CONFIG       += resources
QT += opengl
QT += xml
QT += xmlpatterns
QT += script

TARGET = filter_ao
QT += opengl

RESOURCES += \
    filter_ao.qrc
```

Make sure that the output of from the build contain a call to $QTDIR/rcc, like

```
/usr/bin/rcc -name filter_ao filter_ao.qrc -o qrc_filter_ao.cpp
```

Comment: No such luck, at least not as I'd hoped.  Here is the [makefile](http://pastebin.com/u3NAsqCG)  I can see rcc call but it's still listed under compiler_rcc_clean and the qrc file doesn't seem to generate.  Did a quick search through the whole subdir just to make sure.

Comment: Note that compiler_rcc_clean only calls the DEL command. The relevant target for rcc is in line 132 (release\qrc_filter_ao.cpp: filter_ao.qrc...) which should call rcc in line 136.

Comment: It's my understanding that all lines under a particular target, like compiler_rcc_clean, are a part of that target?  So to me, everything up to line 138 is part of the compiler_rcc_clean.

Comment: No, not quite. Line 132 starts a new target - a target starts in column 0 and is terminated with a colon, optionally followed by a list of dependencies (unless it is a phony target like dist:). The associated commands start with a tab character.
You can even call this target directly, like `make  release\qrc_filter_ao.cpp` (I assume you are using nmake? I only have a mingw environment currently available). You could check  if this works, at least.

Comment: +1 for good call, it looks like my problem is related to Qt Creator and not the makefile itself.  I'd like to mark as answer but my original problem still stands, Qt Creator doesn't build the qrc file.